# How do I open a new command line window from an sh script and then pass in multiple commands

Tags: windows, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm currently working on a sh script that needs to open 3 or 4 command line windows . Each window should then set some local variables and run a script (which will occupy the command line window).

Essentially what I'm looking to do is have a sh script that runs the following:

> start set NODE_ENV=prod && node app
>   start set NODE_ENV=dev && node app
>   start set NODE_ENV=demo && node app

Except what happens is only the variable is set and the node command is executed from the window where the shell script was executed.

This is running on windows through the command line, but I'm also happy to use git bash as well.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: I am looking for a real solution to this question. With windows i believe i can invoke the cmd in a visible way. On linux i don t see a way to implement easily a cross distro compatible way. Any suggestion is much appreciated, i must be missing something existing. I m particualrly looking for a node solution, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to open a new command window, I was however able to find a way to run three ongoing processes through one command window.

You simply put an `&` character after the ongoing process in your sh script. Hope this is of some use to someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
 /bin/bash /path/to/script <args>
```

I hope i read this right but its early so excuse me if i read the question wrong. In bash to run a bash script from within a bash script you would use

Comment: Hey Scott, you might be onto something, but it's not quite what I'm after. I'd like to be able to run 3 bash scripts at once essentially (they are ongoing scripts which don't close essentially - unless I manually close them). The only way I can think this would work is to spawn 3 new command line windows. I can open a command line window fine (using the start command and passing a command in), but I need to be able to set some local variables and then execute a command. The problem is I haven't had any luck passing in more than one line to the new command line.